# Почему elif invalid syntax?

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет. Почему у меня выдаёт ошибку? Вот код.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!✋\nМы продаём голду, аккаунты и промокоды по самым сладким ценам!\nВсегда мечтал стать крутым в стандоффе? Тогда тебе к нам!')
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    accounts = types.KeyboardButton('КУПИТЬ АККАУНТ')
    promo = types.KeyboardButton('КУПИТЬ ПРОМОКОД')
    gold = types.KeyboardButton('КУПИТЬ ГОЛДУ')
    markup.add(accounts, promo, gold)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите, что хотите купить', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == 'КУПИТЬ АККАУНТ':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
        buy_account = types.KeyboardButton('АККАУНТ С НОЖОМ И ПЕРЧАТКАМИ - 230₽')
        buy_account_1 = types.KeyboardButton('АККАУНТ С ТЫЧКАМИ - 175₽')
        back_to_menu = types.KeyboardButton('НАЗАД В МЕНЮ')
    markup.add(buy_account, buy_account_1, back_to_menu)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите аккаунт, который хотите купить', reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == 'Назад':
    bot.send_message(m.c.i, "Вы вернулись назад", reply_markup=accounts, promo, gold)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

По моему, всё довольно очевидно.

Посмотрите на блок, в котором находится elif

В Питоне блоки выделяются отступами.

у вас после `if` идет отступ и 4 строки кода. Которые выполняются **если условие истинно**

А потом у Вас обратный отступ.

С точки зрения языка, те две строки, которые содержат код

```
    markup.add(buy_account, buy_account_1, back_to_menu)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите аккаунт, который хотите купить', reply_markup=markup)
```

это то, что будет происходить после **закончившегося** блока `if` (и будет выполняться независимо от истинности условия в `if`)

А потом у вас идет `elif`. И интерпретатор питона думает "черт побери, откуда он взялся, если `if` уже давно закончился?"

Как исправить? думаю, добавить отступы у этих двух строк.

**Дополнение, дополненное чуть позже**

Смотрите, у Вас по ходу работы над программой появляются ошибки. попробуйте прочитать сообщение об ошибке, и, если само сообщение у Вас не вызывает никаких идей - просто погуглить с этим сообщением об ошщибке.

Этот совет звучит очевидно, но он мог бы решить массу вопросов. например, я вижу ваше удаленное сообщение. И ошибка в нём "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument" говорит о нарушении синтаксиса.

Ну, то есть, при вызове функции есть понятие "positional argument" и "keyword argument". И всегда, вот прямо всегда positional argument должны быть **до** keyword argument в списке аргументов. Так устроен мир. И это написано много где!

Comment: Теперь появилась другая ошибка. Прикреплю ниже.